# Copying via PHP results in URL mismatch

Tags: php, copy

I have a code which would copy a file from one location to another.When I try to access the copied file,I am receiving file not found error,but the file is actually present in that location.

```
Location of source file:codebase\assets\default_pages\
Location of file to be copied:codebase\site_users\general\test\
Source file:home.php
Destination file:test.php[Rename while copying]

Code:Test.php[location:codebase\models\user_entry\]
copy("../../assets/default_pages/home.php","../../site_users/general/test/test.php");
```

When I try to access `test.php`,it gives me following error,

```
 /codebase/site_users/general/ravikanth/codebase/site_users/general/test/test.php
```

But when I create a file manually[without code]everything works fine.Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you must be having some sort of redirect inside your php file. 
can you paste the content of the file which your trying to access after copying

Comment: Thanks.I was making a check and then redirecting it to a specific code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple file permission problem. Try chmod command. Maybe manually you are creating/copying with root but Apache or whatever the PHP runs on does not have a permission.

Comment: Tried by giving permission after copying the file,but still not able to get around this error.